# Akka as a Queuing cluster alternative?

Tags: jms, akka, actor, amqp

I have a setup in which apps communicate using AMQP queues. For a number of reasons, we have a cluster based on RabbitMQ.

My questions is simple: how could someone drop RabbitMQ (or AMQ in case of JMS) in order to use Akka? I don't really understand the notion of a cluster when using Akka and no broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Akka is not a message broker. You see, Akka Actors is a model for building both horizontally and vertically scalable applications that are fault tolerant in nature. As for the actual transport of messages across Akka Actor nodes: any transport that adheres to the send guarantees would work, this is by default using TCP, but anyone is free to hook up AMQP, JMS, 0MQ, UDP or whatever transport they fancy.

So, you'd switch to Akka Actors if you'd want to write your systems/apps in a model that doesn't make assumptions on where things are physically located.

As for the Akka Clustering (p2p & experimental in Akka 2.1) I do not understand what you question is, please elaborate.

Hope this helps,

√

Comment: Ok, after reading your answers and also studying the doc I understand now the subtle (to my head) difference of the two and also why my "cluster" question was not in accordance to what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear! Happy hAkking!